# ubuntu 15.04 can't turn off auto login for specific account

Tags: auto-login

So I've been trying to revert the auto login option to off, but it doesn't seem to work, when i restart i always get the log in without asking for password. The file **lightdm.conf** is currently with these lines:

[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=blank

blank isnt any configured account...

Any one knows how to solve this?

regards,

Comment: Are you actually referring to *autologin* (system goes straight to user's desktop, bypassing the lightdm screen altogether) or *passwordless login* (normal lightdm login screen appears, user's desktop is loaded after clicking the account name)?

Comment: I think its the first option since i have a password set. It just goes straight into the desktop.

Comment: Edit: No, the lightdm screen appears after a restart. And the account password box appears with the "log in" text that when i press goes immediately to the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be describing is *passwordless login* rather than *autologin*, and is controlled by membership of the nopasswdlogin Unix group rather than the lightdm configuration.

You can check whether your user is a member of that group using the `id` command

```
id
```

or (if logged in as a different user)

```
id username
```

I don't know a way to modify group memberships via the GUI, but from a terminal you should be able to use the standard user/group modification utilities `usermod` or `gpasswd` e.g.

```
sudo gpasswd --delete username nopasswdlogin
```

To see all members of the nopasswdlogin group, you can use

```
getent group nopasswdlogin
```

Comment: maxrunner@maxrunner-Qosmio-F60:~$ id maxrunner
uid=1000(maxrunner) gid=1000(maxrunner) groups=1000(maxrunner),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),120(nopasswdlogin),125(sambashare)
maxrunner@maxrunner-Qosmio-F60:~$ getent group nopasswdlogin
nopasswdlogin:x:120:maxrunner