# Automatic Login even though it is disabled in Settings. How to turn off?

Tags: kubuntu, login, auto-login

Kubuntu 15.10.

I used to be asked for my password at every startup or reboot. Suddenly I am always being automatically logged in, even though I never checked "Automatic Login" in Settings.

In Settings -> User Manager, the checkbox "Automatic Login" is NOT checked. I tried checking it, rebooting, removing the check and rebooting again - but I still got Automatic Login even though it is disabled in Settings.

How can I turn on begin asked for my password / turn off Automatic Login again ?

(P.S. This started happening when I changed locale (from LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 to LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in /etc/default/locale) - don't know if that was the cause though)

Comment: Are you referring to autologin, or [passwordless login](http://askubuntu.com/questions/639179/ubuntu-15-04-cant-turn-off-auto-login-for-specific-account/639203#639203) (they're different things)?

Comment: @steeldriver It appears to be autologin.  My account (which is the only account on the system, there are no other users) is not listed in the nopasswd groep.
`14:28 ~ $ id LB79`
`uid=1001(LB79) gid=1001(LB79) groups=1001(LB79),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),127(sambashare)`
`~ $ getent group nopasswdlogin`
`~ $` 
The computer boots straight to the desktop, there is no screen where you can choose an account to login.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help, because Kubuntu 15.10 should also use the same DisplayManager as 16.04

- Find out what DisplayManager you are using [DM-List](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager) 
  (KUbuntu 16.04 is using SDDM)
- Then you can open the right configuration file (/etc/sddm.conf)
- There you can delete the entry as superuser ([Autologin]
  User=john
  Session=plasma.desktop)
- Auto-Login is off

All information are taken out of

> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM

I got the right hint at a kubuntu chat from a friendly user.

---

This answer is a copy of an answer from this question:

[Kubuntu 16.04 | How to turn off auto-login after start - GUI not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808812/kubuntu-16-04-how-to-turn-off-auto-login-after-start-gui-not-working/809173#809173)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Actually in the meantime I had to do a reinstall of my Kubuntu system (for reasons not related to the above post), and since then I don't have the problem anymore. So I can't comment if this solution would work...