# Kubuntu 16.04 | How to turn off auto-login after start - GUI not working

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, login

After having Kubuntu installed with the option for Auto-Login turned on, I now would like it to be off. I do not want to have a auto-login at start up (what makes every other login senseless).

I have set it here as "off" but that doesn't change anything. The button does not seem to be working.

[image]

How can I switch it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Find out what DisplayManager you are using [DM-List](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager) 
  (KUbuntu 16.04 is using SDDM)
- Then you can open the right configuration file (/etc/sddm.conf)
- There you can delete the entry as superuser ([Autologin]
  User=john
  Session=plasma.desktop)
- Auto-Login is off

All information are taken out of

> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM

I got the right hint at a kubuntu chat from a friendly user.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all variants from the Network!
*My info is actual for Kubuntu 20.04!*
and found the next:

**1) check logs here if any issues**
`journalctl -r -p3`

**2 create a config file (new), there is no by default**

```
sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf
```

**type this!**

```bsh
[DAEMON]
Relogin=false
User=nik
Session=plasma.desktop
[Autologin]
Relogin=false
User=nik
Session=plasma.desktop
```

**Session** name is case sensitive! I tried to use  Plasma.desktop
and it did not work

I tried to find where to take all session names but I did not find that,
so hopefully this will help anyone to save time